# Absolute Values and its Inequalities

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Find $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies both $|2x - 3| < 5$ and $|x + 1| > 2$ simultaneously.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE: In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Actually I tried solving them separately hoping to get a clue. But, I didn't. I'm kind of new to this so I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we solve $|2x-3|<5$. We have $2x-3<5$ and $-(2x-3)<5$

So, \begin{align}2x-3&<5\\
2x&<8\\
x&<4\end{align}

and \begin{align}-(2x-3)&<5\\
-2x+3&<5\\
-2x&<2\\
x&>-1\end{align}

Therefore, $-1<x<4$

Then we solve $|x+1|>2$. We have $x+1>2$ and $-(x+1)>2$

So \begin{align}x+1&>2\\
x&>1\end{align}

and \begin{align}-(x+1)&>2\\
-x-1&>2\\
-x&>3\\
x&<-3\end{align}

Therefore $x>1$ or $x<-3$

We can then combine these two, to give us the final answer of $$1<x<4$$

---

This (rather messy, sorry!) number line shows how we have combined the two results - the red line is the result of $|2x-3|<5$, the green line is the result of $|x+1|>2$, and the blue line is the answer to the question (anywhere there is a red and green line):

[image: Number line]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: if you can solve both inequalities, it shouldn't be too hard to combine the results.

$$|2x - 3| < 5 \iff  -5 < 2x - 3 < 5 \iff \ldots \iff x \in S_1$$

$$|x + 1| > 2 \iff x + 1 < -2 \;\vee\; x + 1 > 2 \iff \ldots \iff x \in S_2$$

Once you have the solutions sets to both inequalities, take the intersection:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l} |2x - 3| < 5 \\ |x + 1| > 2\end{array}\right. \iff x \in S_1 \cap S_2$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

$|2x-3|<5\Leftrightarrow -5<2x-3<5\Leftrightarrow -1<x<4$

$|x+1|>2 \Leftrightarrow x+1<-2 \;\text{or}\; x+1>2 \Leftrightarrow x<-3 \;\text{or}\; x>1$

Hence solutions of inequalities are
$$
1<x<4
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response.